# Mind boggling problem regarding RCON Protocol implementation in C#

Tags: c#, sockets, sleep, stringbuilder

I once again need your help figuring out this problem of mine...Been already a day and I can't seem to find out why this is happening in my code and output.

Ok.....so basically I am trying to implement the [RCON Protocol](http://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Source_RCON_Protocol#Receiving) of Valve in C#, so far I am getting the [expected output](http://paste2.org/p/1396829) given the code and sample usage below:

**Usage:**

```
RconExec(socket, "cvarlist");
```

**Code:**

```
private string RconExec(Socket sock, string command)
{
    if (!sock.Connected) throw new Exception("Not connected");

    //sock.DontFragment = true;
    sock.ReceiveTimeout = 10000;
    sock.SendTimeout = 10000;
    //sock.Blocking = true;

    Debug.WriteLine("Executing RCON Command: " + command);

    byte[] rconCmdPacket = GetRconCmdPacket(command);
    sock.Send(rconCmdPacket); //Send the request packet
    sock.Send(GetRconCmdPacket("echo END")); //This is the last response to be received from the server to indicate the end of receiving process
    RconPacket rconCmdResponsePacket = null;

    string data = null;

    StringBuilder cmdResponse = new StringBuilder();

    RconPacket packet = null;
    int totalBytesRead = 0;

    do
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[4]; //Allocate buffer for the packet size field
        int bytesReceived = sock.Receive(buffer); //Read the first 4 bytes to determine the packet size
        int packetSize = BitConverter.ToInt32(buffer, 0); //Get the packet size

        //Now proceed with the rest of the data
        byte[] responseBuffer = new byte[packetSize];

        //Receive more data from server
        int bytesRead = sock.Receive(responseBuffer);

        //Parse the packet by wrapping under RconPacket class
        packet = new RconPacket(responseBuffer);
        totalBytesRead += packet.String1.Length;

        string response = packet.String1;
        cmdResponse.Append(packet.String1);

        Debug.WriteLine(response);

        Thread.Sleep(50);

    } while (!packet.String1.Substring(0,3).Equals("END"));

    Debug.WriteLine("DONE..Exited the Loop");
    Debug.WriteLine("Bytes Read: " + totalBytesRead + ", Buffer Length: " + cmdResponse.Length);

    sock.Disconnect(true);

    return "";
}
```

**The Problem:**

This is not yet the final code as I am just testing the output in the Debug window. There are a couple of issues occuring if I modify the code to it's actual state.

1. Removing `Thread.Sleep(50)`

   - If I remove `Thread.Sleep(50)`, the output doesn't complete and ends up throwing an exception. I noticed the 'END' termination string is sent by the server pre-maturely. This string was expected to be sent by the server only when the whole list completes. 
     [image: Exception Thrown] I tested this numerous times and same thing happens, if I don't remove the line, the list completes and function exits the loop properly.
2. Removing `Debug.WriteLine(response);` within the loop and outputting the string using `Debug.WriteLine(cmdResponse.ToString());` outside the loop, only partial list data is displayed. If I compare the actual bytes read from the loop with the length of the StringBuilder instance, they're just the same? Click [here](http://paste2.org/p/1396882) for the output generated.

Why is this happening given the two scenarios mentioned above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not considering that `Socket.Receive` very well could read fewer bytes than the length of the supplied buffer. The return value tells you the number of bytes that was actually read. I see that you are properly storing this value in a variable, but I cannot see any code that use it.

You should be prepared to make several calls to `Receive` to retrieve the entire package. In particular when you receive the package data.

I'm not sure that this is the reason for your problem. But it could be, since a short delay on the client side could be enough to fill the network buffers so that the entire package is read in a single call.

Try using the following code to retrieve package data:

```
int bufferPos = 0;
while (bufferPos < responseBuffer.Length)
{
    bufferPos += socket.Receive(responseBuffer, bufferPos, responseBuffer.Length - bufferPos, SocketFlags.None);
}
```

Note: You should also support the case when the first call to `Receive` (the one where you receive the package's data length) doesn't return 4 bytes.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I was misled with the assumption that whatever size I put in the receive method would be the expected number of bytes that would be sent by the server through a single call. I didn't even bother checking the number of bytes received! I will give this a try when I get back home. Thanks again!

Comment: Update: Problem Solved :) Thanks a lot! I'll keep this in mind moving forward.